# link a folder in document library to another document library in sharepoint 2010

Tags: document-library, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a document library dl1 which has folder folder1 and folder2. Then i have another document library named dl2. I want to link the folder2 to the document library dl2..any suggestions?

Update : whenever a user clicks on the folder2 content of dl2 are displayed

Comment: could you say more about what "link" means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the Link to a Document content type in the dl1 library to create a link to the dl2 library.

Comment: Hi Eric, could you please elaborate on ur answer.Thanks

Comment: In dl1 you can enable content types (advanced settings) and add the content type "Link to document". Then you can click the dropdown in "New Document" to select "Link to document" enter some text and the URL of dl2. It'll not show as a folder but you get the link functionality

Comment: Yes, sorry for being a bit brief. That's how to configure it as Per mentions, this topic comes up often and has appeared a couple times this week.

Comment: This works fine---but when you create the network places with the library in question, you can see the folder shortcut but cannot open it